# The required package exo-2 was not found on your system

Tags: compiling, ubuntu-mate

```
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for exo-2 >= 0.12.0... not found
*** The required package exo-2 was not found on your system.
*** Please install exo-2 (atleast version 0.12.0) or adjust
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

I am trying to compile Thunar 1.8.2.

I can not figure how to install exo-2.

Can someone help?

Comment: All the dependecies showed obsolete? @Terrance

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from source code needs installation of special development packages (build dependencies).

At first you need to open Software & Updates application from GUI or by `software-properties-gtk` command. Then  check `[ ] Source Code`  on the first tab and confirm reloading software lists.

The Thunar [is packaged in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/thunar), so you can use the command below to get its build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep thunar
```

To install additional dependency use:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-dev
```

And then fix libraries as @Terrance suggested in comments:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I did so and got. E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list @N0rbert

Comment: @fixit7 That is where you uncomment the `deb-src` lines in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: I did that. I got it to compile but thunar now will not run. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it. thunar: error while loading shared libraries: libthunarx-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory I also tried fixing broken passages. @Terrance

Comment: @fixit7 Run `sudo ldconfig` to fix errors when loading shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks Terrance so much. Thought I was going to have to use Clonezilla. @Terrance